# Error in finding the right elements from an array in fibonacci sequence c++

Tags: c++, arrays, fibonacci

So i am changed the code a little bit. It still doesn't work but i think i am little bit closer. The program should check if the number you put in (inside bar[100]) match the fibonacci numbers(stored in fib[30]) and then print the ones that match.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long x, bar[100], fib[30];

    cout << "Cate numere sunt in array? = ";
    cin >> x;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            cout << "bar[" << i << "]=";
            cin >> bar[i];
            }

    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 1;
    fib[2] = 2;
        for (int i = 3; i <= 30; i++) {

            fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
        //  cout << fib[i] << " ";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            bool fibonacci = false;
            int j = 0;
                while (j < 30  && !fib) {
                // the mistake is here ( ' || ' instead of ' && ')
                    if (fib[j] == bar[i]) {
                        fibonacci = true;
                        }
                    j++;
                }
                if (fibonacci) {
                    cout << bar[i] << " ";
            }
    }


return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `1 / sqrt(5)` -- This yields an integer, not a floating point value.  Use `1.0 / sqrt(5);` or since these are just constants, just define a constant instead of computing the square root of 5 repeatedly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, why would `1 / sqrt(5)` yield an `int`? `sqrt`, afaik, always returns a floating point value, and `1 / [float]` would be a float too... See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/_wWdbE)

Comment: oops, my mistake.  Should be a double.

Comment: This is not the way to use Binet's formula in a loop.  The `bar[i]` need not be used at all in the formula.  Instead, just an increasing value of `i` is used, and then the result is assigned to `bar[i]`.

Comment: Also, the goal of your program seems confusing to me.  The user is supposed to enter what exactly?  Their guess as to what the `nth` Fibonacci number is, and your loop says if they are correct or not?  It's hard to read your code, since it is not using English as the strings.  Also `if (bar[i] = ` -- shouldn't that be `if (bar[i] == `?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you need to put any numbers you want , then the program needs to check if they are a part of fibonacci

Comment: If that's the case, then you should place those computed Fibonacci numbers in a set, and then take the user's input and search the set to see if the value is there.  The only part of your code I see that's understandable is the attempt of using Binet's formula.  Otherwise, your explanation doesn't fit at all with what you've coded.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah i think that should be a possible answer also, but that what i need to do. I was thinking that I could verify if a number is part of the fibonacci sequence IF it's a match for the Binet's formula.

Comment: @VictorBînzar -- Yes, but to do what you've suggested, you need to precompute the Binet values and put them in a map or set, regardless of what the user inputted.  Then you check the user's guess against the map / set.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok, I don't know how to do it, but I was thinking maybe another array with the elements of the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Yes another array, and just do a linear search (that is the simplest in concept).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what do you think now? Isn't it better now? And of course there a mistake because it doesnt work properly.

Comment: Lol i discovered it on my own! So there at the logical operator in while-loop, it should be 'or' || instead of 'and' &&. Now it works pretty well. It feels sooo good.

Answer (score 0):

The code above works pretty well for me. It prints out every right number of the Fibonacci sequence you introduce in the bar[100] array. Special thanks to @PaulMcKenzie and everyone who helped!

Answer (score -1):

Move the bar[1] bar[2] and bar[3] initialization outside of the for loop. They are not defined outside the scope of it.

Comment: Yes, they are defined outside the scope. `bar` is defined at the beginning of `main`

Comment: That said, assigning indices 0~2 the same value over and over again _is_ pointless, so that should be moved out and only done once.

Comment: @underscore_d, agreed, but it's not going to fix anything.